# Need to implement an algorithm to obtain the average value of the fields of the graph structure( graph tree)

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, ecmascript-6, graph-algorithm

I have such a task, please help with the solution!
There are graph nodes which have objects.
Please help me find the average value of the 'val' fields and the node with the minimum value of the 'val' field

Example graph structure(graph tree) Also i need implement this on JavaScript. Thank You very Match

```
var graph_structure = {
val: 74,
child: [{
    val: 17,
    child: [{
        val: 34,
        child: [{
            val: 34,
            child: [{
                val: 65,
                child: [{
                    val: 28,
                    child: [{val: 85},
                        {
                            val: 30,
                            child: [{val: 68},
                                {
                                    val: 10,
                                    child: [{
                                        val: 100,
                                        child: [{
                                            val: 21,
                                            child: [{val: 21},
                                                {val: 64}]
                                        },
                                            {
                                                val: 86
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },

                ]
            },
                {
                    val: 22,
                    child: [{
                        val: 17,
                        child: [{val: 65}]
                    }]
                }]
        },
            {
                val: 53,
                child: [{
                    val: 3,
                    child: [{
                        val: 98,
                        child: [{
                            val: 90,
                            child: [{
                                val: 76,
                                child: [{
                                    val: 87,
                                    child: [{
                                        val: 52,
                                        child: [{val: 56}]
                                    }]
                                },
                                    {val: 47},
                                    {
                                        val: 40,
                                        child: [{
                                            val: 80,
                                            child: [{val: 34}]
                                        },
                                            {
                                                val: 23,
                                                child: [{val: 47},
                                                    {val: 92}]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                val: 98,
                                                child: [{val: 89},
                                                    {val: 16},
                                                    {val: 10}]
                                            }]
                                    }]
                            },

                            ]
                        },
                            {
                                val: 35,
                                child: [{
                                    val: 89,
                                    child: [{
                                        val: 76,
                                        child: [{
                                            val: 50,
                                            child: [{val: 51},
                                                {val: 90}]
                                        },
                                            {
                                                val: 69,
                                                child: [{val: 93},
                                                    {val: 98},
                                                    {val: 62}]
                                            }]
                                    }]
                                }]
                            }]
                    }]
                },

                ]
            }

        ]
    }]
},
    {
        val: 98,
        child: [{val: 85},
            {
                val: 85,
                child: [{
                    val: 58,
                    child: [{
                        val: 81,
                        child: [{
                            val: 36,
                            child: [{
                                val: 45,
                                child: [{
                                    val: 96,
                                    child: [{
                                        val: 15,
                                        child: [{
                                            val: 11,
                                            child: [{val: 96}]
                                        }]
                                    },
                                        {
                                            val: 48,
                                            child: [{
                                                val: 4,
                                                child: [{val: 74},
                                                    {val: 1}]
                                            },
                                                {val: 7}]
                                        }]
                                },
                                    {
                                        val: 84,
                                        child: [{val: 9},
                                            {
                                                val: 81,
                                                child: [{
                                                    val: 10,
                                                    child: [{val: 67}]
                                                }]
                                            }]
                                    }]
                            },
                                {
                                    val: 85,
                                    child: [{val: 53},
                                        {
                                            val: 7,
                                            child: [{
                                                val: 47,
                                                child: [{
                                                    val: 74,
                                                    child: [{val: 30},
                                                        {val: 7},
                                                        {val: 12}]
                                                },
                                                    {val: 22}]
                                            },
                                                {
                                                    val: 56,
                                                    child: [{
                                                        val: 51,
                                                        child: [{val: 45}]
                                                    },
                                                        {
                                                            val: 54,
                                                            child: [{val: 20},
                                                                {val: 62}]
                                                        }]
                                                }]
                                        }]
                                }]
                        }]
                    },
                    ]
                },
                    {
                        val: 62,
                        child: [{
                            val: 36,
                            child: [{
                                val: 39,
                                child: [{val: 20}]
                            },
                                {
                                    val: 10,
                                    child: [{
                                        val: 91,
                                        child: [{
                                            val: 81,
                                            child: [{
                                                val: 59,
                                                child: [{
                                                    val: 19,
                                                    child: [{val: 59},
                                                        {val: 16}]
                                                },
                                                    {
                                                        val: 35,
                                                        child: [{val: 30}]
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        val: 6,
                                                        child: [{val: 27}]
                                                    }]
                                            },
                                                {
                                                    val: 89,
                                                    child: [{
                                                        val: 60,
                                                        child: [{val: 59}]
                                                    }]
                                                }]
                                        }]
                                    },

                                    ]
                                }]
                        },
                        ]
                    },
                ]
            },

        ]
    },
    {
        val: 8,
        child: [{
            val: 56,
            child: [{
                val: 55,
                child: [{
                    val: 41,
                    child: [{
                        val: 17,
                        child: [{
                            val: 15,
                            child: [{
                                val: 40,
                                child: [{
                                    val: 55,
                                    child: [{val: 50},
                                        {
                                            val: 99,
                                            child: [{val: 86},
                                                {val: 90}]
                                        }]
                                }]
                            },
                                {
                                    val: 85,
                                    child: [{
                                        val: 36,
                                        child: [{
                                            val: 39,
                                            child: [{val: 45}]
                                        }]
                                    }]
                                },
                                {
                                    val: 78,
                                    child: [{
                                        val: 24,
                                        child: [{
                                            val: 93,
                                            child: [{val: 8}]
                                        },
                                            {
                                                val: 26,
                                                child: [{val: 5}]
                                            }]
                                    },
                                        {val: 36}]
                                }]
                        },
                            {val: 13}]
                    },

                    ]
                },
                    {
                        val: 10,
                        child: [{
                            val: 0,
                            child: [{
                                val: 77,
                                child: [{
                                    val: 46,
                                    child: [{
                                        val: 72,
                                        child: [{
                                            val: 17,
                                            child: [{val: 10},
                                                {val: 67}]
                                        },
                                            {val: 48},
                                            {val: 60}]
                                    },
                                        {
                                            val: 98,
                                            child: [{
                                                val: 12,
                                                child: [{val: 61},
                                                    {val: 27}]
                                            }]
                                        }]
                                }]
                            },
                            ]
                        }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
    }
]};
```

Comment: please add the code, you tried and the wanted result as well. what do you mean with *" minimum value of the `val`"*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create recursive function with `for...in` loop and first calculate total sum and total number of nodes and then use those 2 values to calculate average.

```js
var graph_structure = {"val":74,"child":[{"val":17,"child":[{"val":34,"child":[{"val":34,"child":[{"val":65,"child":[{"val":28,"child":[{"val":85},{"val":30,"child":[{"val":68},{"val":10,"child":[{"val":100,"child":[{"val":21,"child":[{"val":21},{"val":64}]},{"val":86}]}]}]}]}]},{"val":22,"child":[{"val":17,"child":[{"val":65}]}]}]},{"val":53,"child":[{"val":3,"child":[{"val":98,"child":[{"val":90,"child":[{"val":76,"child":[{"val":87,"child":[{"val":52,"child":[{"val":56}]}]},{"val":47},{"val":40,"child":[{"val":80,"child":[{"val":34}]},{"val":23,"child":[{"val":47},{"val":92}]},{"val":98,"child":[{"val":89},{"val":16},{"val":10}]}]}]}]},{"val":35,"child":[{"val":89,"child":[{"val":76,"child":[{"val":50,"child":[{"val":51},{"val":90}]},{"val":69,"child":[{"val":93},{"val":98},{"val":62}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]},{"val":98,"child":[{"val":85},{"val":85,"child":[{"val":58,"child":[{"val":81,"child":[{"val":36,"child":[{"val":45,"child":[{"val":96,"child":[{"val":15,"child":[{"val":11,"child":[{"val":96}]}]},{"val":48,"child":[{"val":4,"child":[{"val":74},{"val":1}]},{"val":7}]}]},{"val":84,"child":[{"val":9},{"val":81,"child":[{"val":10,"child":[{"val":67}]}]}]}]},{"val":85,"child":[{"val":53},{"val":7,"child":[{"val":47,"child":[{"val":74,"child":[{"val":30},{"val":7},{"val":12}]},{"val":22}]},{"val":56,"child":[{"val":51,"child":[{"val":45}]},{"val":54,"child":[{"val":20},{"val":62}]}]}]}]}]}]}]},{"val":62,"child":[{"val":36,"child":[{"val":39,"child":[{"val":20}]},{"val":10,"child":[{"val":91,"child":[{"val":81,"child":[{"val":59,"child":[{"val":19,"child":[{"val":59},{"val":16}]},{"val":35,"child":[{"val":30}]},{"val":6,"child":[{"val":27}]}]},{"val":89,"child":[{"val":60,"child":[{"val":59}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]},{"val":8,"child":[{"val":56,"child":[{"val":55,"child":[{"val":41,"child":[{"val":17,"child":[{"val":15,"child":[{"val":40,"child":[{"val":55,"child":[{"val":50},{"val":99,"child":[{"val":86},{"val":90}]}]}]},{"val":85,"child":[{"val":36,"child":[{"val":39,"child":[{"val":45}]}]}]},{"val":78,"child":[{"val":24,"child":[{"val":93,"child":[{"val":8}]},{"val":26,"child":[{"val":5}]}]},{"val":36}]}]},{"val":13}]}]},{"val":10,"child":[{"val":0,"child":[{"val":77,"child":[{"val":46,"child":[{"val":72,"child":[{"val":17,"child":[{"val":10},{"val":67}]},{"val":48},{"val":60}]},{"val":98,"child":[{"val":12,"child":[{"val":61},{"val":27}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}

function calc(data) {
  return (function repeat(data, res) {
    for(let i in data) {
      if(data.val) {
        res.nodes++;
        res.total += data.val
        if(!res.min) res.min = data
          else if(res.min.val > data.val) res.min = data
        }  
      if(typeof data[i] == 'object') repeat(data[i], res)
    }
  return res
})(data, {min: null, nodes: 0, total: 0})
}

let res = calc(graph_structure);
res.avg = res.total / res.nodes;

console.log(res)
```